# Can we put background style into <tr>?

Tags: html, css

I cannot ensure whether the background-image style is valid for `<tr>` because the image doesn't display in my computer.

```
<tr style='background-image: url(/images/Bet188/LeftMenu/xyz.png>...</tr>
```

Comment: Have you tried `…/xyz.png);'>`

Comment: ^_^..cool mistake...it is OK, i am sure that we all have funny mistakes sometimes..or had one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In reviewing the CSS spec for tables, it seems to indicate that one should be able to apply a background image to a table row much like applying a background to any specific cell or to the table at large.
>
> However, only Firefox 1.0.3 (and likely all the way back to 1.0) managed to apply the background correctly. In both IE 6 and Opera 7.54, the background image that is declared on the row gets applied to each cell contained within. This creates an ugly repeating pattern that is rather troublesome.

source: [snook.ca](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/applying_a_back)

By the way your code:

```
<tr style='background-image: url(/images/Bet188/LeftMenu/xyz.png>...</tr>
```

will not work... You forgot the closing ' before your > :

```
<tr style='background-image: url(/images/Bet188/LeftMenu/xyz.png'>...</tr>
```

Comment: @Younes: Start lines with `>` to mark quotes... it's better style.

Answer (score 2):

If you fix the typo (missing close parenthesis and quotes) it should work. (You should be using a CSS file anyway, together with an HTML validator.)

However, you must be aware that some browsers do not handle backgrounds in `<tr>` properly if you also have a background in some on the row cells (namely, some IE versions).

Answer (score 2):

do this...

`<tr style="background-image: url('/images/Bet188/LeftMenu/xyz.png');">...</tr>`